# Angular nested http request with previous request as parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm building an application where i list events in an html table. An event holds some information about itself but also a user-id, this user-id is the identifier for the user in the mongodb database i'm using

I want to use the $http service provided by angular to first get the events, then looping through the data in the response and issue another get to fetch the user object for each user-id. Every event carries exactly one user-id. The user object is then appended onto the existing event object as a nested object.

However when i do this the user-id variable i use for the calls turns out to be unassigned, as the http calls are async. I've read something about trailing/chaining the calls but i don't get it to work.

Below is the code i've tried amongst what seems to be 100 tries..

**Controller**

```
"use strict";
(function () {
    var app = angular.module("app-test");

    app.controller("testController", function ($scope, $log, $http, $route) {

    var getAllQualityEvents = function () {
        return $http.get("http://localhost:5001/api/qualityevent")
            .then(function (response) {
                return response.data;
            });
    };

    var getUserForEvents = function (data) {
        var result;
        for (var d in data) {
            $http.get("http://localhost:5001/api/user/" + d.userId)
                .then(function (response) {
                    $scope.qualityEvent[d]["user"] = response.data;
                });
        };
    };

    // Run every loop.
    getAllQualityEvents()
        .then(function (data) {
            $scope.qualityEvent = data;
            getUserForEvents(data);
            });
    });
})();
```

**Html document (only the path using the controller)**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl">
        <h1>Test events</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Username</th>
                    <th>User Id</th>
                    <th>Something</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="qualityEvent in qualityEvents" class="{{qualityEvent.isQualityOk ? 'bg-success' : 'bg-danger'}}">
                    <td scope="row">{{qualityEvent.user}}</td>
                    <td>{{qualityEvent}}</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Error message**

My api returning an error message telling me "undefined" is not a valid id.

Comment: `data` in the `getUserForEvents()` method is most likely an array so you would need `data[d].userId` not `d.userId`

Comment: ill put it in an answer so you can accept it for others to see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` in the `getUserForEvents()` method is most likely an array so you would need `data[d].userId` not `d.userId`